# Connecting 3700 Watt induction hob - special wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I got this [VÄLBILDAD](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/vaelbildad-induktionskochfeld-ikea-300-schwarz-20467592/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=surfaces&utm_campaign=shopping_feed&utm_content=free_google_shopping_clicks_HomeAppliances&gclid=CjwKCAiA8ov_BRAoEiwAOZogwcHrrskrB-X70Vi5iCyJAKfonZS4MnLZeT1ASjMk6kFhGbVDwWLUGBoCrH0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) 2 plate induction hob at Ikea in Germany.
I received it with electric cable connected to the hob but without a plug.
I wouldn't try to connect it myself if I thought this induction requires any special wiring,
but from what I read it seems to only require a normal 230V 16A socket which I have in my kitchen.
The hob is 3700 Watt.

The manual says:

> This appliance has a type "Y" attachment with a cable type H05V2V2-F. MONO-PHASE connection: min. section of the conductors: 3x1,5mm2

I'm attaching some photos of the wires and the connection diagram.

Can someone tell me if I can just buy a 230V 16A electric plug [like this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Schwabe-62220-double-earth-contact/dp/B00GHDGM74/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=elektrischer%20stecker&qid=1608714297&sr=8-5) for example and connect the hob to a 16A socket, or should I call an electrician?

Thank you very much.

I'm in Germany.

[image: induction pre wired]
[image: Cable with no plug and connection diagram]

Comment: That kind of job better be done by qualified electrician. Device need dedicated circuit and may be house wiring need alternation. If you connect to existing receptacle another load can run in same time and electrical circuit will be overloaded.

Comment: Thanks @user263983, Since I know the circuits in my house, I can make sure the hob is on its own 16A circuit. Are there more things I should consider?

Comment: Check you local electrical code. It may some rules about the place, distance to water tap, to another electrical devices, receptacles, ground fault protection, etc. Probably you can do it, but get consulted by local.

Comment: I would think that the real question would be whether your local laws allow you to do your own electrical work like this. In the US, this is perfectly acceptable when working on a residence you own (but prohibited in many other situations). From what I understand, a lot of European countries have much more restrictive rules on what can be done DIY.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you already have a Schuko socket (and it's the only socket on that circuit), you can just put a plug like that on the cable and plug it in.

16A at 230V is 3680W, which is probably what the 3700W actually is (rounded up for marketing purposes).

Edit: I noticed in the instructions for the induction hob that it's possible to limit the power used by the hob. If you're worried about your wiring not being good enough, or if the circuit breaker trips when you're using the hob at full capacity, you can limit it to 3.5kW, 3kW, or even less.

Answer (score 1):

The link you gave is pretty much could be working if you have a EU type of plug.

L1, N1, GND is pretty much solid, it doesn't need special cable or wiring just use the cable that meets the requirement. "min. section of the conductors: 3x1,5mm2"

All plug that meets the standard usually has a rated Amperage with a safety rating is 150% of max load.

If you push up to the rated power just a bit up from bares ambient temp. if you push with 150% (16Ax150%=25A) it will warm enough.

And last you will probably not getting this stove full Watt since usually people use the stove just 1/2~3/4 from a full range, you ain't no hurry aren't you?

check the label is stated TOT.3700Watt which mean **total power is 3700Watt** (full power) unless you use this stove always full power then you must consider buying a larger plug.

Or use Circuit breaker 16A and >20A switch :) much safer that way rather than just plug.

And check if your house/apartment has a good cable inside that can handle 16A per wire. Because it's useless using good plug but the wire is not big enough to handle it.